ASP.NET Core use dependency injection for custom type in xml output formatter
In my ASP.NET Core project, I have a custom type which needs to be serialized using some external service:
public struct MyCustomType 
{
    private int value;
    public MyCustomType(int value) { this.value = value; }

    public static implicit operator int(MyCustomType value) { return value.value; }
}

public class SerializerService 
{
    public string Encode(MyCustomType val) => ((int)val).ToString();
    public MyCustomType Decode(string val) => new MyCustomType(int.Parse(val));
}

I added a custom Json converter (MyCustomTypeJsonConverter) which uses the SerializerService to serialize/deserialize MyCustomType.
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<SerializerService>();
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureJsonOptions>();
        var app = builder.Build();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}

public class MyCustomTypeJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyCustomType> 
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider sp;

    public MyCustomTypeJsonConverter(IServiceProvider sp) 
    {
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    public override MyCustomType Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)  
    {
        return sp.GetRequiredService<SerializerService>().Decode(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyCustomType value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(sp.GetRequiredService<SerializerService>().Encode(value));
    }
}

class ConfigureJsonOptions : IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions> 
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider sp;

    public ConfigureJsonOptions(IServiceProvider sp) 
    {
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    public void Configure(JsonOptions options) 
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyCustomTypeJsonConverter(sp));
    }
}

This all works fine and well. Now I need to add support for XML serialization.
I replaced:
builder.Services.AddControllers();

with
builder.Services.AddControllers( options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

Obviously, I need to customize MyCustomType for xml serialization as well. Only option seem to be IXmlSerializable interface:
public struct MyCustomType :  IXmlSerializable 
{
    private int value;
    public MyCustomType(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public static implicit operator int(MyCustomType value) { return value.value; }
    System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) { /*need to obtain SerializerService here*/}
    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) { /*need to obtain SerializerService here*/}
}

Is there some option to achieve custom type xml serialization without implementing IXmlSerializable? Is there some other xml serializer - which is suitable to be used as asp net core output formatter and have custom type serialization?

Hi @Ozren Kinkela, for other xml serliazer, you could custom XmlSerializerOutputFormatter and XmlSerializerInputFormatter.

Hi @Rena, how do I customize XmlSerializerOutputFormatter to achieve custom type serialization?
